# Gatling pass collected variable from a ChainBuilder to another ChainBuilder from a different class

Tags: java, performance-testing, gatling

I'm trying to pass a value collected from a test, to another test, but looks like the gatling session object is kept inside classes and is not allowing other classes to use it.

My code looks like this:

Test class 1

```
public class BooksStore{

public static ScenarioBuilder getScenario() {

ChainBuilder getBooks =
            exec(http("Get Books IDs")
                    .get(path/to/books/ids)
                    .check(jsonPath("$.idList[1]").saveAs("firstBookId")));

return scenario("Get all books ids").exec(getBooks);
}
```

Test  class 2

```
public class Client{

public static ScenarioBuilder getScenario() {

ChainBuilder readBook =
            exec(http("Get Book by ID")
                    .get(path/to/book/${firstBookId}));
             
return scenario("Get book by id").exec(readBook);
}
```

Simulation class

```
public class MySimulation extends Simulation {

HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol =
        http
                .baseUrl("https://bookylova.com")
                .acceptHeader(AllAcceptHeaders)
                .header(Authorization, getGetAccessToken());

{
    setUp(
            BooksStore.getScenario().injectOpen(
            rampUsers(10)
            .during(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .andThen(
            Client.getScenario().injectOpen(
            rampUsers(10)
            .during(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            )).protocols(httpProtocol);
  }
}
```

I can run another exec function chained to **getBooks** and save the value in session, but it won't work to be called in **readBook** . Also tried to store variable outside class in another one then read it, but is not working.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how things work.

Scenarios are virtual users' journey.
Different scenarios mean different virtual users.
Using `check` saves the data in the Session of the virtual user that executed the request. So this data is not available for other virtual users, all the more if they belong to other scenarios.

This is not how you should be using Gatling. You should have 1 single scenario where virtual users first get a book and then read it.

I really recommend that you go through [Gatling tutorials](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/tutorials/) and [free online trainings](https://gatling.io/academy/).

Answer (score 0):

Pass it through a queue.   One pushes to the queue, another reads from the same queue.   You have options such as RabbitMQ or even leveraging a cloud queue provider.   Most of the cloud providers are silly cheap on this, where a 100,000 messages a month may cost you a dollar.

Using a queue also has other advantages in that you can pass data between virtual user processes running on completely different machines, or even different tools exercising distinct portions of a system, such as Gatling to exercise a web service associated with inventory updates, the result is placed on a queue where it is picked up by LoadRunner to use the same data in a terminal virtual user interface as part of a warehouse management system.